# Systemd: how to create a script that runs before any other

Tags: systemd, raspbian

I'm customizing the file-system of Raspbian Stretch and I need to set up something at boot *before* the other application starts. Example, mounting `/var` on `tmpfs` I need to re-create the relevant folder for lighttpd or samba.

I tried to put these lines in `rc.local` but it starts too late.
Is already there a suitable script that runs earlier?

Otherwise I'm going to make my own service. I'm reading through the documentation:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html

but I'm unsure which target I have to use.
I guess something like `local-fs.target` on "Before" and "Wants".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `systemctl list-dependencies` and pick the relevant units to add to the `before` attribute.

For my system that would be

- var-lock.mount
- var-log.mount
- var-run.mount
- var-tmp.mount